# Node Js/Expresss api call using information from client

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, get

So I am writing a webapp to get information from the steam api and I had some cors issues, so I wrote a node/express server to do the actual api call and then the client-side app gets the json off my server. This is working, but only if the api call is hard coded on my server. How can I supply the server with a userid from the "sid" form field from my client?

Server code:

```
var express = require('express');  
var request = require('request');

var app = express();  
function proxy(){
  app.use('/', function(req, res) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    var apiServerHost = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=[APIKEY]&steamids=";
    var userId = 76561197972495328;
    var url = apiServerHost+userId;
    req.pipe(request(url)).pipe(res);
  });
}

proxy();


app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

Client code:

```
function submit(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var sid = document.getElementById("idform").elements[0].value;
        $.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/", function(result){
            console.log(result);
            console.log(result.response.players[0]);
            for(i in result.response.players[0]){
                document.getElementById("main").appendChild(document.createTextNode(i + " : " + result.response.players[0][i]));
                document.getElementById("main").appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: The second argument for `$.getJSON` is data you can send to the server, like any ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument for `$.getJSON` is data you can send to the server, like any ajax call.

```
var sid = document.getElementById("idform").elements[0].value;

$.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/", {sid: sid}, function(result){ ...
```

and catch it in Node

```
app.use('/', function(req, res) {
    var sid = req.query.sid || "";

    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

    var qs  = "?key=[APIKEY]&steamids=" + sid;
    var url = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/" + qs;

    req.pipe(request(url)).pipe(res);
});
```

Comment: thanks this worked except I had to use `document.getElementById("idform").elements[0].value;` instead of `$("#idform").val();`

Comment: Oh, okay, `idform` is a form, and `elements[0]` gets the first input in that form. I missed that one and just changed it (wrongly). I'll change it back, but `$('#idform :input').first()` would probably work as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Server code:

```
var express = require('express');  
var request = require('request');

var app = express();  
function proxy(){
  app.use('/', function(req, res) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    var apiServerHost = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=[APIKEY]=";
    var userId = encodeURIComponent(req.query.sid);
    var url = apiServerHost+userId;
    req.pipe(request(url)).pipe(res);
  });
}

proxy();


app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

Client code:

```
function submit(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var sid = document.getElementById("idform").elements[0].value;
        $.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/?sid=" + encodeURIComponent(sid), function(result){
            console.log(result);
            console.log(result.response.players[0]);
            for(i in result.response.players[0]){
                document.getElementById("main").appendChild(document.createTextNode(i + " : " + result.response.players[0][i]));
                document.getElementById("main").appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks I used part of yours and part of the other answer's